# select content between paired brace in pyCharm or any IDE

Tags: python, ide, selection, pycharm, braces

I just wonder is there any shortcut to select content in the paired brace instead by selecting them manually in pyCharm or any other IDE? For example,

I want to select

```
np.mean((predicted == validation).astype(float))
```

from

```
print('\n Accuracy:' + str(100*np.mean((predicted == validation).astype(float))) + '%')
```

So I do not have paired everything and verify it by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **extending selection** `Ctrl + W`. Place the cursor inside and repeat pressing until everything you want is selected. To **shrink** the **selection** use `Ctrl + Shift + W`.

For your example extending selection will work as follows if you place cursor on `predicted`:

```
predicted
predicted == validation
(predicted == validation)
(predicted == validation).astype
(predicted == validation).astype(float)
((predicted == validation).astype(float))
np.mean((predicted == validation).astype(float))
```

If you place it on mean, it goes as follows:

```
mean
np.mean
np.mean((predicted == validation).astype(float))
```

Experiment to get a feeling for it.

There is also **smart selection** with `Ctrl + Alt + V`, but this is explicit for refactoring. Try it and see if it is what you need. It will split the expression by creating a new variable, assigning the selected expression to it and use the variable in the outer expression. So if I use it for your expression selecting your part it will refactor it to:

```
mean = np.mean((predicted == validation).astype(float))
print('\n Accuracy:' + str(100* mean) + '%')
```